# Print walls coming out with gaps/holes

Tags: print-quality

I'm using a Prusa i3 MK3, with Prusa Slicer 2.2.  It seems to print the raft fine, but then when it gets to the main part, it seems that the extrusion comes out thinner, and leaves gaps/holes in the layers.

- Filament: PLA
- Layer height: 0.1 mm
- Infill: 30% Gyroid
- Print speed:

  - Perimeters: 35 mm/s
  - Infill: 50 mm/s
  - First layer speed: 20 mm/s
- Extruder temp: 205 °C
- Nozzle diameter: 0.4 mm
- Retraction length: 2 mm

[image: Photo of a 3D printed model with gaps/holes]

Comment: That is a major example of underextrusion! Have you you investigated the regular suspects? Lower hotend temperature, lower retraction to 0.8 mm @35 mm/s, filament diameter check, increase layer height?

Comment: I was initially at 215, so I just dropped it to 205 for this print and saw similar results.  I'll try dropping it a little bit more.

Comment: Very interested to learn if lowering it a bit more helped.